Tensorflow dataset from_generator
I have an infinte generator:
def get_random_distribution_from_generator(N=10):
    while True:
        k = random.randint(0, 1)
        if k==0:
            cls = (1,0)
            sample = np.random.uniform(-2, 8, LEN)
        elif k==1:
            cls = (0,1)
            sample = np.random.normal(3,1,LEN)
        yield sample, cls

It draws a fixed number of random numbers from either a uniform or a normal distribution. It yield the sample and a tuple encoding the class (one-hot-encoding).
Now I want to create a Tensorflow dataset from this.
tfd = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(get_random_distribution_from_generator(5), output_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=(LEN), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), tf.TensorSpec(shape=(2), dtype=tf.int8, name=None)))
tfd_batch_wise = tfd.shuffle(1000).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(1)

I can use this to start to train a neural network. Well, since the generator is infinite, it trains forever.
Is there a way to have a flexible but fixed number of values in the Tensorflow dataset?
I know:

I could use take(N) and create a fixed size Tensorflow dataset from the infinte version. But I do not want to keep it in memory. I chose the generator in order to be flexible concering the size of the dataset.

I can create a generator that yields a fixed number of elements. This is not very flexible. If I want to change the size, I have to change the code.


I tried:

create a generator class. Here I get the error message that the genertor must be callable, which is not true after creating the object.

Is there a simpler solution that

lets me specify the maximum number of elements that will be created for the Tensorflow dataset from an infinte generator.
The generator must be callable to be used in from_generator method.


Hi @Eddy, there is one approach custom generator class that gives you number of samples but you can also put the fixed number of elements when creating  the dataset and also we need the generator class callable so that we can use with
tf.data.Dataset.from_generator. it is flexible because you can easily change num_samples when creating the RandomDistributionGenerator.Try this ,if you still need more help let me know, Thanks.
